# Resolution in Android app

Tags: android, drawable, resolution

When I create my Android app i create 6 drawable folders:

1. drawable-hdpi.  // resolution 1.5 x
2. drawable-mdpi. // resolution 1 x
3. drawable-xhdpi. // resolution 2 x.
4. drawable-large. // resolution 2 x.
5. drawable-xlarge. // resolution 2.5 x.
6. drawable-xxhdpi. // resolution 3 x.

In every folder i put the same image with different size according to android device resolution and screen size.

Is this correct? or this is insufficient for my android app ?

Comment: How accurately do you want your images to be displayed? Android does a very good job of scaling drawables. The key here is to test your app on different devices with different screen sizes and resolutions and see how it looks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

When i make project in `Android Studio` it automatically generates the folder structure for `drawable-` i.e

```
-- res
 | -- drawable-hdpi     (for low density screens)
   -- drawable-mdpi     (for medium density screens)
   -- drawable-xhdpi    (for high resolution screens)
   -- drawable-xxhdpi   (for extra high resolution screens)
```

> The drawable-xxxhdpi qualifier is necessary only to provide a launcher icon that can appear larger than usual on an xxhdpi device. You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images.

I think that the above is more than sufficient for an android application. And actually `xxhdpi` is more than enough for a high res tab or phone. Please go through [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: for sure this is not sufficient  because my android app want to run on tablet, tab 7 , note 3 and all devices...

Comment: I can confirm that `xxhdpi` will be sufficient for your needs. In case you want to add support for `tv` you can add `tvdpi` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, it's not necessary to put all the same images with different size in every folder. If you put the full set of images in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder, the system will re-size the image for other density automatically. Sometimes, some image may lost important details while re-sizing, then you should redesign a proper image for the density and put in the corresponding folder, not ALL images.
**Second**, `xlarge`/`large`/`normal`/`small` are the size of screen, `ldpi`/`mdpi`/`hdpi`/`xhdpi`/`xxhdpi` are the density of screen, the resolution is the combinations of size and density.
**Finally**, you may prepare just one set of image in `res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder, then design different layout for different screen size in `res/layout-***` folders, just set different `dp` in `width`/`height`/`margin` etc..
**Reference**: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you now i understood the concept more , but i think it not necessary to create multiple layout for different screen size, its better to create multiples images with different size and one xml layout. also you can specify dimens for multiple screen

Comment: That's right and wrong, to create multiples images with different size and one xml layout will control the quality of images for better user experience. But, it will makes the size of apk be much fatter.